# Passing geolocation javascript variable to rails infinite reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, geolocation

Ok so I am trying to create a map that is on one page. The javascript is supposed to locate the user and then pass those variables to rails so it can find nearby Store model locations. I cannot seem to figure out what I need to do to get it to work. It is in an infinite loop thanks to the body onload = 'getLocation()' and the window.location function in the .js file. Also the url is /findme.

controller

```
def show
    @nearby_stores = (params[:lat].present? && params[:lon].present?) ? Storeuser.near([params[:lat], params[:lon]], 50) : []
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
```

view

```
<body onload = 'getLocation()'>

    <div class = 'map'>
      <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
    </div>

    <div class= "test"></div>
    <h3>Nearby locations</h3>
    <ul id="nearby_locations">
        <% @nearby_stores.each do |storeuser| %>
        <li><%= link_to storeuser.storename, profile_path(storeuser) %>(<%= storeuser.distance.round(2) %> miles) </li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</body>
```

application.js

```
var x = document.getElementById("map");
        function getLocation()
        {
            if (navigator.geolocation)
            {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
            }
            else{x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
        }
        function showPosition(position)
        {
            handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { markers: { maxRandomDistance: null } });
            handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
                markers = handler.addMarkers([
                    {
                        "lat": position.coords.latitude,
                        "lng": position.coords.longitude,
                        "picture": {
                            "url": "https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/13/13028-64.png",
                            "width":  36,
                            "height": 36
                        },
                        "infowindow": "You!"
                    }
                ]);
                handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
                handler.fitMapToBounds();
            });
            var lat = position.coords.latitude
            var lon = position.coords.longitude
            var parsed_data = {location: {lat: lat, lon: lon}}
            window.location = ('/findme?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon);
        }
```

Comment: When you do `window.location = ...`, you realize this will change the current page, right? You probably want to append your data after a `#` so the page doesn't refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok stupid me

a coworker fixed it for me

```
if (!window.location.search) {
                window.location = ('/findme?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon);    
            }
```